# Error in the set up snippet given by VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently started using VS Code. Their webpage gave the following snippet to start with C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

But when I run this it gives the following error:

```
test.cpp:9:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
                      ^
                      ;
test.cpp:11:29: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (const string& word : msg)
```

I am completely new to using this IDE, and using C++ in general. Are there any libraries I need to install to run this?

Thank you

Comment: This needs to be compiled as C++ 11 code, which seems to not be the default. Search for the error message ("is a C++11 extension") online.

Comment: you must be using a very old compiler, try updating to a newer one

Comment: every week this question passes here at SO, does anybody use the search function at SO?